# Angular error TS4111: Property 'email' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['email']

Tags: angular

Hi my friends good day for all, i'm having this issue solving this trouble with reactives forms, I've find a lot of answers on internet and none seems to work for me I have no idea what to do, i tried to put email like this ['email'] but the problem persists

can some one help me with this?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdDIe.png)

there is my code

**login.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  FLogin: FormGroup = this.fb.group({ 
    email: ['', [Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required]]
  })

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

}
```

**login.component.html** my problem is in the ng if sentece

```html
<form class="login100-form" autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="FLogin">
                
    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-49">
        Login
    </span>

    <div class="wrap-input100 m-b-23">
        <span class="label-input100">Email</span>
        <input class="input100"
               type="email" 
               name="email" 
               formControlName="email"
               placeholder="Ingrese su email">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
        <span class="form-text text-danger"
        ngIf="FLogin.controls.email.errors"></span> 
        <span>Debe colocar un correo valido</span>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap-input100">
        <span class="label-input100">Password</span>
        <input class="input100"
               type="password"
               name="password" 
               formControlName="password"
               placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña">
        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="text-right p-t-8 p-b-31"></div>
    
    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
            <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
            <button type="submit"
                    class="login100-form-btn"
                    [disabled]="FLogin.invalid">
                Login
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-col-c p-t-60">
        <span class="txt1 p-b-17">
            ¿No tienes cuenta?
        </span>

        <a routerLink="/auth/registro" class="txt2">
            Crear una aquí
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I think it should be `FLogin.control['email'].error`. Please try it

Comment: @Vijay you forgot two `s`: is `controls` and `errors`, another way `FLogin.get('email')?.errors`

Comment: This can be closed